# How can I share module in pytorch?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, embedding

I want to share my `embedding` in `Encoder` and `Decoder`, I do it something like this:

```
from torch import nn


class FooDecoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embedding):
        super().__init__()
        self.embedding = embedding

class FooEncoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, embedding):
        super().__init__()
        self.embedding = embedding

class Foo(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.embedding = nn.Embedding(10, 10)
        self.encoder = FooEncoder(self.embedding)
        self.decoder = FooDecoder(self.embedding)

model = Foo()
```

But I find that I will have two different params in `state_dict`:

```
state_dict = model.state_dict()
print(state_dict.keys()) # odict_keys(['embedding.weight', 'encoder.embedding.weight', 'decoder.embedding.weight'])
```

It seems `PyTorch` copy the `embedding`, I want to know:

1. `embedding.weight` `encoder.embedding.weight` `decoder.embedding.weight` will always keep the same in forward propagation and backward propagation?
2. Does this mean parameter increase if I do so?)(Because I have three embeeding weight)
3. Do I have any better way do this?